# Good German phrase for "lone wolf"?

Tags: english-to-german

I am looking for a good German word(s) for the English "(a)lone wolf". Practically I am looking for not only a simple dictionary translation, but for a secondary/metaphorical meaning as well, if it exists.

Comment: Can You elaborate on what you consider the primary and secondary meaning?

Comment: I guess the secondary meaning is not the literal meaning, so in this case lone wolf = a person who depends only on himself and is distant from the other people.

Comment: I don't know the English "lone wolf". I don't know what you came up with when doing your research. Did you use a dictionary? I just tried 3 different dictionaries and those agree on "Einzelgänger". At least, now I know what a lone wolf is. -1 anyway.

Comment: http://www.dict.cc/?s=lone+wolf

Comment: @Em1 I didn't asked for a dictionary equivalent, but for a metaphorical equivalent, which I mentioned clearly in my question. It differs mostly a lot from the simple dictionary translation (which I also could translate to f.e. "allein Wolf" or so). Although I had to at least check this in a dictionary, simply I didn't thought it could be found it them. My previous attempts to find metaphorical equivalents were mostly unsuccessful based on leo.dict/google attempts, and I though, native speakers could give much better alternatives. Maybe this explanation is enough for a vote change/hold removal?

Comment: @PeterHorvath After your edit I'm willing to retract my downvote. However, I don't see what the "primary" meaning is as imho only the metaphorical meaning exists. If you relate to the "literal meaning" as primary, well, it should be obvious that "Einzelgänger" is not a verbatim translation. Either way, this question is "off-topic" or "unclear what your asking", so I stay with my close-vote and won't vote for reopen.

Comment: Eine metaphorische Äquivalent wurde hier gefragt, _nicht_ eine literale Bedeutung! Das hätte ich auch sehr einfach mit einem beliebigen Wörterbuch finden können. Die Frage sollte wiedergeöffnet werden.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

For the metaphorical meaning, the idiomatic term is `Einzelgänger`.

Answer (score 24):

The literal translation “Einsamer Wolf” is something you could say in German as well.

Comment: Not only could say, but in fact you do. And it has quite a different connotation than "Einzelgänger" (solitaire), probably exactly the same as lone wolf in English.

Answer (score 10):

"Einzelkämpfer" and the similar "Einsamer Krieger" are common; they apply to non-competetive settings but *do* imply that the person is actually doing something (alone), as opposed to just being alone as a general rule.

Examples:

> Alle sitzen in der Sonne, aber Klaus mäht den Rasen, der einsame Krieger!
>
> Viele arbeiten lieber in Gruppen, aber Claudia ist eine Einzelkämpferin.

Answer (score 2):

[Wiktionary](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Einzelg%C3%A4nger) lists the (imho) nice alternative "Eigenbrötler" to "Einzelgänger". It adds a little pinch of eccentricity if so desired.

Answer (score 1):

I have to add a little more explanation, in English there is also the word **loner** which is best translated as **Einzelgänger**. The loner might be someone who simply hides and has no contact to outer world. He usually avoids every conflict with others.

In contrast the additional word **wolf** emphasizes the fact he is brave and a real hard fighter for something even if there might be hard resistance against him or his opinion. In German the best translation is **Einzelkämpfer** or **Einsamer Krieger** or **Einsamer Wolf**.

Answer (score -1):

If you want a somewhat heavy literary allusion, there's ["Steppenwolf"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steppenwolf_%28novel%29)

Comment: Welcome to German Language! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.