# How to say "when it comes to...." in German

Tags: translation, english-to-german, proverb

" when it comes to love even the smartest people become stupid"

Comment: This can be easily answered with a dictionary and is therefore off topic. But see https://m.dict.cc/englisch-deutsch/when%20it%20comes%20to%20....html

Comment: It might help to avoid close votes if you could clarify whether you want the more general question from the headline answered (easy dictionary lookup), or whether you would like to focus on the body text question (not so easy).

Comment: @idmean I think the OP is asking for a metaphorical equivalent, not for a translation (for example, "lone wolf" sound best translated as [Einzelganger](https://german.stackexchange.com/q/12266/4788)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The often heard "Liebe macht blind" is close but not a perfect fit. *Blind* in its literal sense is just one form of sensory input, not really the whole of cognitive processing being impaired. Further: this *blind* is usually directed towards the 'object' of love and desire, not so much towards everything in general. Although both meanings might be understood in more generalised terms, the reverse translation of "Liebe macht blind" would be "Love is blind".

For the actual question:
You might use a direct translation, like:

> Wenn es um die Liebe geht, werden selbst die klügsten Menschen dumm.

This is beginning with what you are looking for, if we only take the question's headline.
But that sounds even less like a proverb than the English original.

To get into idiomatic territory and addressing more the body text of the question, this has to be shortened to something like

> Liebe macht die klügsten dumm.

Or even shorter

> [Liebe macht dumm](https://www.welt.de/wissenschaft/article12127418/Liebe-macht-dumm-zumindest-Meerschweinchen.html)

Answer (score 1):

There is a much shorter german proverb with a similar meaning: "Liebe macht blind". Not exactly the same but close enough.